# Why isn't this working? Javascript, text inputs' values and using them in an if statement

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, input

I think I'm missing something stupidly simple but can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm trying to use 4 values from 4 text inputs and activate an alert when the values = the string value stated.

```
<div id="AnswersFriends">
    <input type="text" align="center" id="TextFriend1" oninput="checkchange">
    <input type="text" align="center" id="TextFriend2" oninput="checkchange">
    <input type="text" align="center" id="TextFriend3" oninput="checkchange">
    <input type="text" align="center" id="TextFriend4" oninput="checkchange">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function checkchange(){
var Ans1 = document.getElementsByID('TextFriend1').value;
var Ans2 = document.getElementsByID('TextFriend2').value;
var Ans3 = document.getElementsByID('TextFriend3').value;
var Ans4 = document.getElementsByID('TextFriend4').value;

if(Ans1=="Joe" && Ans2=="Joe" && Ans3=="Hugo" && Ans4=="Nathan") {
    alert("WellDone"); 
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change this:**

```
oninput="checkchange"
```

**to this for all the input tags:**

```
oninput="checkchange()"
```

**Also, change this:**

`document.getElementsByID('TextFriend1').value;`

**to this:**

```
document.getElementById('TextFriend1').value;
```

then, do the same for the other `getElementById()` `methods`.

Comment: @HugoStiles have a look at this, it will show you how. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

1. To call a function you have to put `()` after its name
2. There is no function called `getElementsByID`, it is `getElementById` (with a singular element and a lower-case d on the end).

Comment: What do you mean put a () after its name, like this: function () checkchange{  or function (checkchange){    (Also thank you for quick reply)